# function to calculate auv for 3 months prior to sampling date

Tags: auc

I have a data frame containing many environmental variables collected over a long period (monthly data). I want to calculate AUC for one variable (e.g.: enso) for three months before the sampling date to see if there is a correlation between other variables with the AUC value calculated. Can someone help me with this r function?

```
the data frame looks like this
| date         | enso     | temp     | x2       |
| --------     | -------- | -------- | -------- |      
| 2003-01-01   | 0.8      |  20      |   0.4    |
| 2003-02-01   | 0.62     |  18      |   0.21   |
| 2003-03-01   | 0.53     |  17      |   0.48   |
| 2003-04-01   | -0.08    |  5       |   0.22   |
```